# I can't figure out why there are extra parenthesis in my console

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm learning the basics of programming and I can't seem to understand why my console is displaying extra parenthesis with the following code:

```
// My Constants Dictionary!

let numberOneScore = 10
let numberTwoScore = 20
let numberThreeScore = 30
let numberFourScore = 40
let numberFiveScore = 50

// Game Stats


func playerOneStats() {
    let playerOneScore = (numberTwoScore) + (numberThreeScore) + (numberOneScore)
    print ("Player one has scored \(playerOneScore) points.")
        }

func playerTwoStats() {
    let playerTwoScore = (numberFiveScore) + (numberOneScore) + (numberOneScore)
    print ("Player two has scored \(playerTwoScore) points.")
        }

func showStats() {
    print(playerOneStats())
    print(playerTwoStats())
        }

showStats()
```

My console shows this:

```
Player one has scored 60 points.
()
Player two has scored 70 points.
()
```

And my question is, why are those extra parenthesis being printed on console at the end of each player's score?

Comment: You're printing a function which is of type `Void` (or `()`).  There's nothing to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showStats` method should be simply calling the other two methods like this:

```
func showStats() {
    playerOneStats()
    playerTwoStats()
}
```

Instead of that, you wrap the two method calls in `print` statements. If those two methods returned a value, then that value would be printed by the `print` statement. However, those methods return no value at all. So that's why you get the empty parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
Player one has scored 60 points.
```

and

```
Player two has scored 70 points.
```

are printed by playerOneStats() and playerTwoStats(), while the () by the unnecessary prints in showStats(). You should do

```
func showStats() {
    playerOneStats()
    playerTwoStats()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already changed it and figured it out!

```
// My Constants Dictionary!
let numberOneScore = 10
let numberTwoScore = 20
let numberThreeScore = 30
let numberFourScore = 40
let numberFiveScore = 50
let initialScore = 150
let missedDart = 0


// Game Stats
func playerOneStats() {
    var playerOneScore = initialScore - numberTwoScore
    playerOneScore = playerOneScore - numberThreeScore
    playerOneScore = playerOneScore - numberOneScore
    print ("Player one has a final score of \(playerOneScore) points.")
        }
func playerTwoStats() {
    var playerTwoScore = initialScore - numberFiveScore
    playerTwoScore = playerTwoScore - missedDart
    playerTwoScore = playerTwoScore - numberOneScore
    print("Player two has a final score of \(playerTwoScore) points.")
        }

playerOneStats()
playerTwoStats()
```

This was my first post on Stack, thank you all guys for your rapid responses! :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of posting your own answer that simply repeats what the other answers already stated, you should accept one of the other answers to indicate that is solved your issue.